# Liquibase: How to skip tables in origin database when using diffchangelog

Tags: informix, liquibase

I'm trying to use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) diffChangeLog with Informix and it fails on a table that has the reserved word "max" as a column name.  I tried to use:

```
--excludeObjects="table:informix.edidef_element"
```

but it does not seem to be honored when getting the base data from the origin database.  (Note: I also found out that the --excludeObjects parameter only works/recognized after the diffChangeLog part of the command.)

The error I get is:

DEBUG 1/22/15 3:05 PM: liquibase: Checking edidef_element.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select max from informix.edidef_element where 0=1'
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: A syntax error has occurred.

I get the same error if I cut and paste the select command into dbaccess.  For now I just want to skip that table, until I get a chance to fix the column name.

Here is my command script:

```
#!/bin/sh
database="edi"

exclude="table:edidat_location,table:informix.edidef_element,column:max,(i?)edidef_element"

./liquibase  --logLevel=debug --defaultSchemaName="informix"  --diffTypes="tables,columns"  \
--driver=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver  \
--url="jdbc:informix-sqli://stmst3.test.trnswrks.com:56670:informixserver=stmst3;database=${database}" --username=khhis  --password="hidden" \
diffChangeLog \
--excludeObjects=${exclude} \
--referenceDefaultSchemaName="informix" \
--referenceUrl="jdbc:informix-sqli://stmsq3.qa.trnswrks.com:56070:informixserver=stmsq3;database=${database}" --referenceUsername=khhis  --referencePassword="hidden"
```

If I can't get Liquibase to skip the table, is there a way to force the select that is generated to include the table name?  If the select was in the form of "select edidef_element.max from informix.edidef_element where 0=1", it would work.

I'm using version 3.3.2.

./liquibase --version
 Liquibase Version: 3.3.2

Comment: What version of liquibase are you using? `includeObjects/excludeObjects` was added in 3.3.2. Did you make sure you're having a version > 3.3.2?

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.2.   It accepts the  the option on the command line, asl long as it is after the "diffChangeLog" 

./liquibase --version returns:<br>
Liquibase Version: 3.3.2